# Acceder a otras propiedades del mismo objeto

Tags: javascript, object

tengo un objeto donde guardo datos para construir una vista y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de acceder a otras propiedades de ese objeto desde otra propiedad en el mismo objeto

Intenté con `this`  pero no funciona

```js
var obj = {

  template: `
  
  Nombre | Edad <br>
  ${this.names.name1} | ${this.age.age1}<br>
  ${this.names.name2} | ${this.age.age2}<br>
  ${this.names.name3} | ${this.age.age3}<br>
  
  `,
  names: {
    name1: 'Emmett',
    name2: 'Paola',
    name3: 'Mushi'
  },
  age: {
    age1: 8,
    age2: 20,
    age3: 3
  }

}

document.write(obj.template);
```

Comment: Pero age es un objeto distinto.. no tienen nada que ver un objeto con otro. porque pensas que son el mismo objeto?

Comment: age y names son parte de obj al igual que template estoy tratando de obtener propiedades de obj desde propiedades de obj @gbianchi

Comment: Ah ok. Cambiaste la pregunta. O la arreglaste. Genial. Y que error te da por consola? Que tipo de lenguaje estas usando para renderizar esto?

Comment: No edite la posición de age ni nada por el estilo, en ese ejemplo sale el error que da por consola _TypeError: this.names is undefined_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un concepto clave para este detalle, **JavaScript no tiene ámbito de bloque *(declaración de objeto)*, más sí de función** , cuando hace referencia a `this` en realidad hace referencia al objeto `window` que es el contexto donde se realizo la llamada al objeto.

Pueden haber dos soluciones al menos para este detalle

Definir dicha propiedad fuera de la declaración del objeto

```js
var obj = {
  names: {
    name1: 'Emmett',
    name2: 'Paola',
    name3: 'Mushi'
  },
  age: {
    age1: 8,
    age2: 20,
    age3: 3
  }

}
obj.template =  `
  Nombre | Edad <br>
  ${obj.names.name1} | ${obj.age.age1}<br>
  ${obj.names.name2} | ${obj.age.age2}<br>
  ${obj.names.name3} | ${obj.age.age3}<br>`

document.write(obj.template);
```

O usar un [getter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/get) qué si se enlaza con una función, por lo cuál la palabra reservada `this`, hará referencia al objeto.

```js
var obj = {
  get template() { return  `
  Nombre | Edad <br>
  ${this.names.name1} | ${this.age.age1}<br>
  ${this.names.name2} | ${this.age.age2}<br>
  ${this.names.name3} | ${this.age.age3}<br>
  `},
  names: {
    name1: 'Emmett',
    name2: 'Paola',
    name3: 'Mushi'
  },
  age: {
    age1: 8,
    age2: 20,
    age3: 3
  },
}


document.write(obj.template);
```

> Note que intentar asignar un valor a `template` no lo cambiará.Lo que
>   si puede hacer es eliminar usando `delete`